# My discord bot keeps getting disconnected for some reason

Tags: python-3.6, discord.py

I haven't changed my bot in weeks and for some reason I would get an error message like this every day for the past 5 or so days https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka8xC.jpg

I don't think the error is caused by my code besides the whole loop thing which I don't know how to fix and it hasn't caused me any problems before, but if you're curious about that part I have the part of code that causes that issue below

I already tried regenerating my token.

```
@client.event
async def dead_check():
    i = 1
    d = datetime.now()
    date = str(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    server = client.get_server(id = '105388450575859712')
    while i == 1:
        async for message in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id='561667365927124992'), limit=9999999):
            if date in message.content:
                usid = message.content.split('=')
                usid1 = usid[1].split(' ')
                count = message.content.split('#')
                cd = message.content.split('?')
                ev = cd[1]
                if ev == '00':
                    number = 0
                elif ev == '01':
                    number = 1
                elif ev == '10':
                    number = 2
                elif ev == '11':
                    number = 3
                name = count[0]
                await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='339182193911922689'), '@here\n' + name + ' has reached the deadline for the **FRICKLING** program.\nThe user has attended ' + str(number) + ' events.')
        async for message in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id='567328773922619392'), limit=9999):
            if date in message.content and message.reactions:
                usid = message.content.split(' ')
                user=await client.get_user_info(usid[0])
                await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='567771853796540465'), user.mention + ' needs to be paid, if you have already paid him - react with :HYPERS:')
                await client.delete_message(message)
        await asyncio.sleep(60*60*24)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(game=Game(name='with nuclear waste'))
    print('Ready, bitch')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(dead_check())
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing the `limit` of those `logs_from` calls?  `9999999` is a pretty big number, and it may have slowed things down enough that the heartbeat isn't being sent at the proper times.  You should also sanitize that image of the error message, it contains your bot token.

Comment: Thank you for noticing my token there.
Also your idea explains why it happens nearly every 24 hours.I'll try changing that and see if that solves the issue

Comment: It worked, ty, mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reducing the limit of those logs_from calls? 9999999 is a pretty big number, and it may have slowed things down enough that the heartbeat isn't being sent at the proper times. You should also sanitize that image of the error message, it contains your bot token.

Credit to Patrick Haugh, but I wanted to close this thread and he didnt post it as an answer